# .NET Firebird ODBC database install not showing as a data source

Tags: vb.net, firebird

I installed Firebird 2.5 and the Firebird ODBC driver "`Firebird_ODBC_2.0.2.153_x64`".  My goal is to connect to a test Firebird database through VB.NET 2008.

I set up a User DSN in the ODBC section of the Control Panel and I have a successful connection.

[image]

[image]

However, when I go to VB.NET and I access the Connect to Database and click on Change to select a different data source, I cannot see a Firebird data source so I could access the fdb database.

What do I need to do to read a Firebird database in VB.NET?

Comment: I suspect that you are seeing only the 32bit data sources not the 64bit. This however should not impede you to use the 64bit datasource in your code if you compile for AnyCPU or 64bit platforms

Comment: I have tried to install the 32bit ODBC driver but it does not show up in control panel under the ODBC (32bit) heading.  If I install the 64 bit one it shows up!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 32 bit Firebird ODBC driver, and configure it through the 32 bit ODBC administrator. Visual Studio is a 32 bit application and therefor only has access to 32 bit ODBC DSNs (and 32 bit ODBC drivers).

As Steve already explained in his comments, a 64 bit or AnyCPU application will actually be able to access a 64 bit ODBC DSN.

However, Firebird has [a database provider for the .NET platform](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/). There is no need to use ODBC.

Comment: I tried to use the DDEX database provider for the .NET platform but it involves using gacutil which gives me the following error: 

"Failure adding assembly to the cache: This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Some posts mention checking if the .NET 4 version of gacutil is present in the SDK but in my case it is not so I cannot go forward.

Comment: I should add that I installed the full .NET 4 Framework in the hope that it installed an updated gacutil.exe.  No luck!

Comment: @monkey64 The default download of the .net provider is for .net 4.5, you need to download on for .net 4, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/

Comment: Getting confused here.  I am using VB.NET 2008 which I thought was based on .NET 3.5.  Am I to use the ADO.NET Data Provider OR DDEX database provider and select 2008 at install?

Comment: The DDEX requires the .NET provider. However you are right, with VS2008 you need a .net 3.5 provider. The last .NET provider to support .net 3.5 is [version 3.2.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/3.2.0/)

Comment: After installing the .NET provider, I get the error: "Error writing to file FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.  Verify you have access to that directory."

Comment: That sounds like you are specifying `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` as a connection string somewhere, not as the driver

Comment: After upgrading to VS2012 I got everything working correctly.